# Find only first word start from a special character java

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to find the only first word that start with a "#" sign in a string in java. There cannot be spaces between the sign and the word as well.

The string "hi #how are # you" shall give the output as :

how

I have tried this with regex, but still could not find a suitable pattern. Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try matching against the following pattern #[a-zA-z]

Comment: what should be result of `"ab cd#ef #gh"`?

Comment: "ab cd#ef #gh" result wil be **ef**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
replaceFirst("^.*?(#\\S+).*$", "$1");
```

Not exactly beautiful, but should work.

This assume the string has such token. If it does not, then you may want to check whether it matches the regex before extracting the token:

```
matches("^.*?(#\\S+).*$");
```

Note that this method will match `"#sdfhj"` in `"sdfkhk#sdfhj sdf"`.

If you want to exclude such case, you can modify the regex to `"^.*?(?<= |^)(#\\S+).*$"`.

Comment: replaceFirst("^.*?(#\\S+).*$", "$1"); Works perfectly.. Thanks nhahtdh.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str ="hi #how are # you";
if (str.contains("#")) {
        int pos = str.indexOf("#");

        while (str.charAt(pos + 1) == ' ')
            pos++;


        int last = str.indexOf(" ", pos + 1);

        str = str.substring(pos + 1, last);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
else{

}
```

**output:**  how

Comment: Wouldn't that also match the "# " and give you an index out of bounds error?

Comment: Failed this case: `"hi # how #dsf are # you"`

Comment: @gtumca-MAC: The OP said that there can't be space between `#` and the string. I expect `#dsf` from my test case, but your code gives `how`.

Comment: see while loop i am increasing starting position if i found space. got it?

Comment: @gtumca-MAC: I don't get what you mean. The output of your code doesn't match what the OP requires.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that xx#xx is wrong word. I thats true try this (if not use `"#(\\w+)"` in Pattern and `m.group(1)` instead `m.group(2)`)

```
String str ="ab cd#ef #gh";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("(^|\\s)#(\\w+)");
Matcher m=pattern.matcher(str);
if(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
else
    System.out.println("no match found");
```

for `"ab cd#ef #gh"` result -> `gh`

for `"#ab cd#ef #gh"` result -> `ab`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex expression:

```
"[^a-zA-Z][\\S]+?[\\s]"
```

unless you know what specific character you are looking for to start with in that case

```
"#[\\S]+?[\\s]"
```

Comment: `[/S]` matches `/` or `S`, and `[^/S]` matches any character **except** `/` or `S`.  If you're trying to match any non-whitespace character, that's `[\S]` or (even better) just `\S`.  And in a Java string literal, you have to escape the backslash: `"\\S"`.

Comment: @AlanMoore You're absolutely right. I'm used to regex in a php context and I keep confusing \ and /.